# Arrayformula for Index Match multiple columns with date values

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am collecting data on intervals and want to display a summary of that data on a single line in a new sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOV4-VwVfwWvhwQ24qkQbCRGxUp74oe0dLWrbj0wiNE/edit#gid=566541214

**Grade Data Sheet**

Each batch of data comes in by date with a `Name`, `Course` and `Grade` like below

Raw data is like this for a large number of `Name` / `Course` / `Grade`:

| Date | Name | Course | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/2022 | Joe | Math | 65-D |
| 10/15/2022 | Joe | Math | 58-F |
| 10/30/2022 | Joe | Math | 50-F |

**Summary Sheet**

Single line that takes each unique `Name-Course` pair and I'm attempting to lookup a grade for each date column.
(note: I'm trying to extract the dates in the columns dynamically as the **Grade Data** sheet expands)

So I've successfully extracted the `Date`s to create new columns, and I am trying to create an index-match that grabs the column date and creates an array of `DATE-NAME-COURSE` and matches `DATE-NAME-COURSE` on the **Grade Data** sheet to return the grade for that student on the `Date`.  The formula works for the first row, but when it fills down it returns the value of the first match.

I can't quite figure out how to reference the single date cell into the array while dynamically filling down.  Not sure if I a different approach, but hopefully this makes sense.

```
=arrayformula(if(len($A2:$A),(index(GradeData!$D2:$D,match(TEXT(C$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&$A2:$A&$B2:$B,TEXT(GradeData!$A2:$A,"yyyy-mm-dd")&GradeData!$B2:$B&GradeData!$C2:$C,0))),""))`
```

The goal is to have **Grade Data** populate automatically, and the **Summary** page to add a column for each new date and fill data down for each student.

Thanks in advance, I have shared the actual sheet above so you can see the data

I've attempted several different ways but can't quite get the dynamic array matches with the date formatting to work.

```
=arrayformula(if(len($A2:$A),(index(GradeData!$D2:$D,match(TEXT(C$1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&$A2:$A&$B2:$B,TEXT(GradeData!$A2:$A,"yyyy-mm-dd")&GradeData!$B2:$B&GradeData!$C2:$C,0))),""))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen the issue in your sheet is that the dates of the header do not match the dates of your source data. I've added a new header line:

```
=LAMBDA(dates,FILTER(dates,regexmatch(dates,"/")))(Transpose(Unique(arrayformula(left(GradeDataVlookup!A4:A,10)))))
```

And just put an IFERROR in order to avoid all the errors of the values without matches:

```
=arrayformula(if(len($A$2:$A),iferror(vlookup(TEXT(C$1,"MM/DD/YYYY")&$A2:$A&$B2:$B,GradeDataVlookup!$A:$E,5,FALSE),""),""))
```

[image]

PS: with MAP or MAKEARRAY you could summarize all the table in just one formula

Comment: Martin that is excellent, thank you so much.  I wasn't familiar with the MAP/LAMBDA/MAKEARRAY functions, so I'm going to give that a try.

Comment: Ok I attemped to create a MAP array, but I'm not exactly sure how to construct the MAP statement however.  I'd want to MAP GradeDataA:E build the Name-Course-Date array, and compare it to the Summary Name-Course-Date.  I tried a few different combos but it is still escaping me.  I made a V2 Summary sheet if you have a moment ot explain how to construct it in a single formula.  Thank you!    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EOV4-VwVfwWvhwQ24qkQbCRGxUp74oe0dLWrbj0wiNE/edit#gid=201145169

Comment: You better use MAKEARRAY. You can set the amounts of rows with COUNTA the first column, and the amount of columns counting the elements in the headers. Then you can use the coordinates (r and c in my example) to determine the INDEX of what to join and VLOOKUP. `=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A), COUNTA(C1:1),LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(C1:1,c)&INDEX(A2:A,r)&INDEX(B2:B,r),GradeData!A:E,5,0),"")))`

Comment: Wow, that is amazing, thank you so much for building that out and explaining how to construct the Row/Column values.  This is great and I'll build from this.  You saved me so much time thank you!