# How do you add an adjacent cell value to a sum if the filtered cell is in a list?

Tags: google-sheets

Sorry for the confusing title and problem. Here's the example:
I'm building a personal finance sheet that returns a table consisting of: **Expected pay date**, **Total bills**, **Savings**, **Net income**, **Pay date**, and **Bills due**.

It pulls from two sources: **Bills** and **Loans**

**Example Bills Data Source**

| Debt | Item | Next Due | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $150 | Phone | 8 Dec 2023 | Monthly |
| $90 | Internet | 3 Jan 2024 | Monthly |
| $1900 | Insurance | 1 Jan 2024 | Semi-annually |
| $850 | Half-rent | 8 Dec 2023 | Bi-weekly |
| $15 | Music | 16 Dec 2023 | Monthly |
| $20 | Patreon | 15 Dec 2023 | Monthly |

**Example Loans Data Source**

| Debt | Item | Next Due | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $450 | Nissan | 15 Dec 2023 | Monthly |
| $300 | Credit Card | 10 Dec 2024 | Bi-weekly |
| $300 | Ford | 6 Jan 2023 | Monthly |
| $800 | Boat | 18 Dec 2023 | Monthly |

I've gotten it to a point where the expected bills between the previous pay date and the next pay date are shown in a column like so:

**Outputted Table**

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **EXPECTED PAY** | $3200 | $3200 | $3200 | . |
| **TOTAL BILLS** | *X1* | *X2* | *X3* | . |
| **SAVINGS** | *SAV_1* | *SAV_2* | *SAV_3* | . |
| **NET INCOME** | *Y1* | *Y2* | *Y3* | . |
| **PAY DATE** | 8 DEC 2023 | 22 DEC 2023 | 5 JAN 2023 | . |
| **BILLS & LOANS DUE** | Phone | Internet | Phone | . |
| . | Half-rent | Insurance | Half-rent | . |
| . | Music | Half-rent | Music | . |
| . | Patreon | Credit-card | Patreon | . |
| . | Nissan | . | Nissan | . |
| . | Credit Card | . | Credit Card | . |
| . | Boat | . | Ford | . |
| . | . | . | Boat | . |

> **Savings **= sum from another data table

> **Net income** = **Expected Pay** - (**Total Bills** + **Savings**)

> **Total Bills** is where I'm struggling to figure out how to add up. This should be the sum of bills listed below in the column. (ex: 8 Dec 2023 would be Phone, Half-rent, Music, Patreon, Nissan, Credit Card, and Boat.) However, I don't know how to add the adjacent ***Debt** cell* to the sum **Total Bills**.

I'm new to sheets and excel, and I'm currently learning python for school. The best method I came up with was to use shove the problem into some Apps Script for the sheet.

I don't know how to approach this problem. I've just been staring at the screen.

Comment: `Semi-annually` would you please describe what this means? How many payments per year, the time period between payments, etc.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: @Tedinoz   Semi-annually - frequency of payment. The full list for frequency is: Weekly, Bi-weekly, monthly, semi-annually, and annually. The tick speed for the columns is 2 weeks (bi-weekly).

Comment: @rockinfreakshow   I'll be sure to do so tomorrow before going into work. I've got some PPI in the primary document that I'll cleanse, then upload. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate Net Pay after expenses by pay period. You have two categories of expenses ("Bills" and "Loans"), and the frequency of payments are:

- Fortnightly
- Monthly
- Six-Monthly
- The answer consists of three tables:

  - Total
  - billsData
  - loansdata

---

**Notes:**

- "Next Due" is calculated date for each expense.

  - This is unnecessary and complicated given the range of payroll dates that might appear in any given spreadsheet. It is easier to reference an "Anniversary date" so that the application of the expense to a given payroll date can be calculated by formula.
- The formula is basically a nested `IF`:

  - `if frequency = "Fortnightly", then X else`
  - `if frequency = "Monthly", then Y, else`
  - `if frequency = "Six Monthly", then Z`
- the payroll dates in row 1 of `billsData` and `loansData` are populated by a query:

  - `=query(totals03!B1:Q1,"select *")`
- the calculation formula for `billsData` is entered in Cell F2:

  - `=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A),COUNTA(F1:1),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(index(D2:D,r)="Fortnightly",index(A2:A,r),IF(and(index(D2:D,r)="Monthly",date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(F1:1,c)),day(index(C2:C,r)))>=index(F1:1,c),date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(F1:1,c)),day(index(C2:C,r)))<(index(F1:1,c)+14)),index(A2:A,r),if(and(D6="Six-Monthly",date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r)))>=index(F1:1,c),date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r)))<(index(F1:1,c)+14)),index(A2:A,r),if(and(index(D2:D,r)="Six-Monthly",EOMONTH(date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r))),5)+1>=index(F1:1,c),EOMONTH(date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r))),5)+1<(index(F1:1,c)+14)),index(A2:A,r),))))))`
- the calculation formula for `loansData` is entered in Cell F2:

  - `=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A),COUNTA(F1:1),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(index(D2:D,r)="Fortnightly",index(A2:A,r),IF(and(index(D2:D,r)="Monthly",date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(F1:1,c)),day(index(C2:C,r)))>=index(F1:1,c),date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(F1:1,c)),day(index(C2:C,r)))<(index(F1:1,c)+14)),index(A2:A,r),if(and(D6="Six-Monthly",date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r)))>=index(F1:1,c),date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r)))<(index(F1:1,c)+14)),index(A2:A,r),if(and(index(D2:D,r)="Six-Monthly",EOMONTH(date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r))),5)+1>=index(F1:1,c),EOMONTH(date(year(index(F1:1,c)),month(index(C2:C,r)),day(index(C2:C,r))),5)+1<(index(F1:1,c)+14)),index(A2:A,r),))))))`
- for sheet = `Total`, the formula for Bills expenses is entered in Cell B4:

  - `=BYCOL(billsData!F2:O,LAMBDA(column,sum(column)))`
- for sheet = `Total`, the formula for Loans expenses is entered in Cell B5:

  - `=BYCOL(loansData!F2:O,LAMBDA(column,sum(column)))`
- for sheet = `Total`, the formulas for `Total Outgoings` is a simple `Sum`, and `Net pay` is simple formula "Expected Pay" less "Total Outgoings"; these formula are copied across columns.

---

h/t: @Martin [Arrayformula for Index Match multiple columns with date values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74738404/1330560)

---

**Sample - Total**

[image: Totals]

---

**Sample - Bills data**

[image: Bills data]

---

**SAMPLE - Loans data**

[image: Loans data]