# Google Sheets Query - Stuck on a date matrix

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, array-formulas

I have a query built, see below, but I want to create a matrix of all possible dates and populate it with each entry, per row.  In the end, I'd like to have a full table to show all possible start dates and all possible end dates, and then an X in the column/row combination that matches the rows below, G & H.

The data is client contracts, with wildly varying start dates and end dates.  In the end, I'm looking to create tables off of this to show history, and forecast 3 years into future(based on future end dates).

```
A & C = Text
I = $
G & H = Dates (in yyyy-mm-dd format)
```

I have a table in a separate tab called "DateRange" in which I have all the possible date ranges in yyyy-mm-dd format, starting at the 1st of the month when the business began, and going to 2026-12-31.  They are in columns A and B respectively.

```
=QUERY(Agreements!A2:K," 
select A, C, I, G, H 
where G is not null
order by A asc 
limit 50000 
label A 'Company', C 'Agreement', I 'Billing Amount', G 'AGR Start Date', H 'AGR End Date' ")
```

[enter image description here][1]

I've tried array formula, and multiple attempts within the WHERE statement to make this work, referencing (DataRange!A1:A;B1:B), but I have not been able to make it work.

Sample output.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3PkD.png

Comment: It may be asking too much to expect forum volunteers to imagine your data. You may get more interest if you include sample data and expected results in table format within your post and/or include a link to a spreadsheet with sample data and some manually entered expected results.

Comment: Thanks, point taken.  First time posting, wasn't sure what to expect.

Comment: Please see my first comment again. A picture does not provide live, copyable data (and yours does not even show ranges). I may not keep up with this post, but sharing data and expected outcomes for that data in one or both of the formats I invited you to share will increase your chances that one of the volunteers here will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in cell G2:

`=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(A2:A), COUNTA(G1:1),LAMBDA(r,c,if(and(index(D2:D,r)<=index(G1:1,c),index(E2:E,r)>=index(G1:1,c)),"Y","")))`

h/t: @Martin [Arrayformula for Index Match multiple columns with date values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74738404/1330560)

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

---